# How can i create an action whenever the task (match in patternstart.finditer) returns None?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to print (match was not found) whenever the task
(for the match in patternStart.finditer(TestString)) does not find a match. I have been stuck on this without any success. Any advice would be appreciated.

The string 'jeke' does not contain a number on purpose so that a match is not found.

```
TestString = 'jeke'
patternStart = re.compile(r'\d')


cnt = 0  # Initialize the counter
wanted1 = [1]  # Defines the 1-based IDs of the matches you want to display
wanted2 = [2]  # Defines the 1-based IDs of the matches you want to display


for match in patternStart.finditer(TestString):
    cnt += 1
    if cnt in wanted1:
        out = match.group()

    else:
        print('match was not found')
```

Attempts I have tried.

```
if match.group() is None:
    print('match was not found')

if out is None:
    print('match was not found')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cnt` to determine whether any match was found:

```
for match in patternStart.finditer(TestString):
    cnt += 1
    if cnt in wanted1:
        out = match.group()
if cnt == 0:
    print('match was not found')
```

Or use a separate `found_match` variable:

```
found_match = False
for match in patternStart.finditer(TestString):
    found_match = True
    cnt += 1
    if cnt in wanted1:
        out = match.group()
if not found_match:
    print('match was not found')
```